# Submit Paypal via URL instead of HTML opens new tabs

Tags: url, paypal, query-string

**The problem:**  "Add to Cart" hyperlink opens a new browser tab for each click rather than consolidating into a single one.

**The ideal solution:**  When the "Add to Cart" hyperlinks are clicked, they will populate the checkout screen in a single tab only.

I use a published google sheet to list some items for sale in a list.  Each item has an adjacent hyperlink labeled "Add to Cart" that has its own unique Paypal URL to pass inputs (I have pasted example below).  This works fine and all however if the user clicks another Add to Cart then it opens up yet another tab.  This doesnt seem like a big deal but it is a bad user experience confuses them all the time and leads to checkout issues.  With HTML this is not a problem but I can't use HTML.

So my question is, is it possible to use a google script to open all the Add to Carts URLs in a single tab?  Or any way to auto-close the first tab in favor of the next one?  Or any way to even open in SAME tab such as mimick target="_self" but in URL format?  Or any other way to do this?

(such as: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&business=bob123%40gmail%2ecom&lc=US&item_name=TOYTRACTOR&item_number=123456789&amount=999%2e00&currency_code=USD&button_subtype=products&no_note=0&cn=Add%20special%20instructions%20to%20the%20seller%3a&no_shipping=2&shipping=10%2e00&add=1&bn=PP%2dShopCartBF%3abtn_cart_LG%2egif%3aNonHosted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the experience with PayPal Standard cart buttons.  I would recommend you switch to building your own cart experience, and then you can use the [cart upload method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/) to build a PayPal Standard request.

Alternatively, you could move to the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/), which gives you more features and functionality.